# How secure is simple admin validation with if statement?

Tags: php

I was wondering how secure a simple php script with an if statement would be as admin password. Say, i have a webpage where i want to login to edit some content. If i created a HTML login script, retrieved the credentials through a post, and validated the password and username through an 'if' statement, such as

```
if ($_POST['pass'] = 'SomePassWordWithAlotOf123456789' and $_POST['user'])
{
     .. do stuff ...
}
```

I'm sure this approach would have major security issues, but I'm curious as to what could go wrong as I'm researching a bit on writing secure PHP applications. The reason why i was interested in this approach, is that it avoids database contact. Also, i am aware of the possibility of brute force attacks with this approach.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: one of problem is plain password. If somebody get your php file, will get the password too, thats why its better to use hashed passwords

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is as secure as how you keep your Web server's FTP/Filesystem access away from users, so no one will be able to see your script's source code.

Therefore, you might want to hash your password before comparing.

```
echo password_hash('SomePassWordWithAlotOf1234567', PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
```

This will output: **$2y$10$AbaPXE/K/mDQWZkRf7JHC.7Z6gKS0YfzdrGOxGXEs24Oh1/224b.C**

---

Now, use this string instead as a comparison key. But you just have to add some flavor:

```
if (password_hash($_POST['pass'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT) == '$2y$10$AbaPXE/K/mDQWZkRf7JHC.7Z6gKS0YfzdrGOxGXEs24Oh1/224b.C')
{
    .. do stuff ...
}
```

Just add username validation and you're ready to go.

Now if you worry about **brute-force** attack, you can add **max 5 login attempts timeout** implementation in your script.

Making use of CAPTCHA in your login form can also prevent automated brute-force/dictionary attacks.

If you are working on a system that is to be delivered to the client, you may want to encode your source code so it won't be easy for them to read script. At least, it will be a tedious job for them to decode your script.

You can use [SourceGuardian](http://www.sourceguardian.com/) to do this.

On the other hand, there are some free obfuscators/encoders available out there, like [PHP Protect](http://www.phpprotect.info/).

Comment: Here, we focused on simple authentication without external data source (e.g. database, flat-file, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

Well, since you can't salt the password without showing the salt in the code you'd be in a troublesome spot. It's safe as long as you and only you have access to the server. If you get hacked your admin-password would be in clear text. As long as the server is safe your password is safe.

To prevent brute-forcing you can add a session that prevents trying to login after five failed attempts or something.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you could use some validation steps and like @PetterPettersson said you can also prevent the user from trying to login too often.

Maybe you can also tell us what do you mean by security problems or secure login